# How do I make OpenVPN split /56 IPv6 block into /64 subnets for each client?

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I want OpenVPN to occupy, for example, `2001:0DB8:5912:1200::/56`, assigning `/64` subnets of it to clients (so they can serve as SLAAC routers if needed).

What should I do? Is OpenVPN alone enough for this or I need to provide IPv6 support without OpenVPN knowing about it (i.e. tunneling though IPv4)?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to have two ranges of IP addresses:

- one (/64) range for the interconnection between the OpenVPN server and the OpenVPN clients (let's say 2001:DB8:0:1::/64);
- one (/56) range that you will subnet into /64 prefixes that you will delegate to the client (let's say 2001:DB8:0:ff00::/56).

For a given client, you can use this [`client-config-dir` file](https://wiki.ldn-fai.net/wiki/OpenVPN_Server_Tutorial#The_solution_we_are_not_using:_client-config-dir):

```
# This client has IPv6 2001:DB8:0:1::1
# and delegated prefix 2001:DB8:0:ff01::/64
ifconfig-ipv6-push say 2001:DB8:0:1::1/64 2001:DB8:0:1::
iroute-ipv6 2001:DB8:0:ff01::/64
```

Notes:

- you might want to use a /48 instead of a /56 for subneting delegated prefixes;
- [RFC3177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3177#section-3) recommends a /48:

> - Home network subscribers, connecting through on-demand or
>   always-on connections should receive a /48.
> - Small and large enterprises should receive a /48.

Comment: OpenVPN client connects to the server over NAT-ed IPv4 and is expected to deliver IPv6 tunnel. `/56` is what `he.net` tunnel broker gives.

Comment: @Vi, Well just use one /64 of your /56 for the interconnection.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I think you can tell OpenVPN to hand out IPv6 addresses and it should do that merrily. However, the IPv6 packets will go nowhere as you are not planning to have a real IPv6 address!

Comment: This is the other way around.

Comment: The numer after slash is the number of set bits in the mask. E.g. for IPv4 `255.255.0.0` = `/16`, `255.0.0.0` = `/8`, `0.0.0.0` = `/0`. Similar for IPv6. `/0` is entire address range, `/128` is a single address.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake and delete the wrong part of the answer to prevent any confusion. Sorry, guys.

Comment: @Vi Please note that he.net gives out a /64 tunnel by default. However, getting a /48 is just a click away. However, the /48 and the /64 do differ in the 3rd word and I am not really sure how it works. ?

For example: 2661:909:f:a43::/64 and 2661:909:e383::/48

Any pointers?